# Flex: create a template app?

Tags: apache-flex

Whenever I start a new project in Flex builder I always have to go and add all my project build paths, adjust the compiler settings, etc. Is there a way I can make a template with all that done and then just click new from template?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but I can think of a workaround or two. Try importing an existing project to a new location, then delete what you don't need.

Even better, you could make a "template" project that has all the settings you want. Then, whenever you want to create a new project, create one, then on the command-line or using Finder (or explorer), copy the project files from the template project in, making sure to update the name correctly. The files that control this are: .flexProperties, .actionScriptProperties, .settings/, and .project, I believe. They are in the root folder of any FB project.